How can I increase the height size of my menu?
How can I increase the height size of my menu?
I want to increase the size of my menu to be full screen instead of it's current size. This is my current code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shot_planner/Project%20Page/Project/Project%20Page.dart';
import 'package:shot_planner/Shot%20List%20Page/Menu/Camera%20Menu%20-%20Phone.dart';
import 'package:shot_planner/Shot%20List%20Page/Menu/Special%20Equipment%20Menu%20-%20Phone.dart';
import 'package:shot_planner/Shot%20List%20Page/Menu/VFX%20Menu%20-%20Phone.dart';

bool shotAddInfoMenuVisible = false;

//----------------------|   AddInfoMenu Widget   |--------------------------------------------------------------------

class AddInfoMenuPhone extends StatefulWidget {
  int shotlistindex;
  int projectindex;
  List<List<FocusNode>> addInfoFocusNodeList;
  ShotListState shotListState;
  Function(String)? onMoreDetailsChosen;
  Function(bool)? onTextDetailsChosen;

  AddInfoMenuPhone(this.shotlistindex, this.projectindex,
      this.addInfoFocusNodeList, this.shotListState,
      {this.onMoreDetailsChosen, this.onTextDetailsChosen});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _AddInfoMenuPhoneState();
}

//----------------------|   AddInfoState State   |----------------------------------------------------------------

class _AddInfoMenuPhoneState extends State<AddInfoMenuPhone> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    print("pop");
    super.initState();
  }

  //MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,

  BottomBar(Widget popupmenu) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        isScrollControlled: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: popupmenu,
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget
            .shotListState
            .addinfoitemgroup[widget.shotlistindex][widget.projectindex]
            .length <=
        4) {}

    // TODO: implement build

    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xff1C1C1C),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),

      // color: Color.fromARGB(255, 35, 35, 35),

      child: Expanded(
        //----------------------|   Close button   |-------------------------------------------------------

        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                child: Container(
                  width: 20,
                  height: 20,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20, top: 10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.grey[400]),
                  child: IconButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.close, size: 12, color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Expanded(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  //----------------------|   Option lists   |--------------------------------------------------------------------

                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey[850],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        itemCount: widget
                            .shotListState
                            .addinfoitemgroup[widget.shotlistindex]
                                [widget.projectindex]
                            .length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return Column(
                            children: [
                              Material(
                                color: Colors.transparent,
                                child: ListTile(
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      vertical: 5, horizontal: 16),
                                  dense: true,
                                  visualDensity: VisualDensity(vertical: -3),
                                  title: Text(
                                    widget
                                        .shotListState
                                        .addinfoitemgroup[widget.shotlistindex]
                                            [widget.projectindex][index]
                                        .toString(),
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      //----------------------|   Toggle selection logic here   |----------------------------------

                                      widget.shotListState.getprojectindex[
                                              widget.shotlistindex] =
                                          widget.projectindex;

                                      if (widget.shotListState.addinfoitemgroup[
                                                  widget.shotlistindex]
                                              [widget.projectindex][index] ==
                                          'Special Equipment') {
                                        widget
                                            .shotListState
                                            .addinfolistname[
                                                widget.shotlistindex]
                                                [widget.projectindex]
                                            .add('Special Equipment');
                                      } else {
                                        widget
                                            .shotListState
                                            .addinfolistname[
                                                widget.shotlistindex]
                                                [widget.projectindex]
                                            .add(widget.shotListState
                                                        .addinfoitemgroup[
                                                    widget.shotlistindex]
                                                [widget.projectindex][index]);
                                      }

                                      widget
                                          .shotListState
                                          .infonamelistpdf[widget.shotlistindex]
                                              [widget.projectindex]
                                          .add(widget.shotListState
                                                      .addinfoitemgroup[
                                                  widget.shotlistindex]
                                              [widget.projectindex][index]);

                                      widget
                                          .shotListState
                                          .infoitemlistpdf[widget.shotlistindex]
                                              [widget.projectindex]
                                          .add('Add');

                                      widget
                                          .shotListState
                                          .getoptionselection[
                                              widget.shotlistindex]
                                              [widget.projectindex]
                                          .add([
                                        widget.shotListState
                                                    .addinfoitemgroupoption[
                                                widget.shotlistindex]
                                            [widget.projectindex][index]
                                      ]);

                                      widget
                                          .shotListState
                                          .getoptionsubtitle[
                                              widget.shotlistindex]
                                              [widget.projectindex]
                                          .add(['']);

                                      List<bool> gettotalbool = [];

                                      for (int i = 0;
                                          i <
                                              widget
                                                  .shotListState
                                                  .addinfoitemgroupoption[
                                                      widget.shotlistindex]
                                                      [widget.projectindex]
                                                      [index]
                                                  .length;
                                          i++) {
                                        gettotalbool.add(false);
                                      }

                                      widget
                                          .shotListState
                                          .addinfolistitem[widget.shotlistindex]
                                              [widget.projectindex]
                                          .add('');

                                      /*addInfoFocusNode.add(FocusNode());

                                    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {

                                      addInfoFocusNode.last.requestFocus();

                                    });

                                    addInfoController.add(TextEditingController());*/

                                      widget
                                          .shotListState
                                          .finalinputcustomize[
                                              widget.shotlistindex]
                                              [widget.projectindex]
                                          .add(false);

                                      /*WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(

                                        (_) => scrollToEnd(widget.projectindex));*/

                                      widget
                                          .shotListState
                                          .shotlist[widget.shotlistindex]
                                              [widget.projectindex]
                                          .add([gettotalbool]);

                                      widget
                                          .shotListState
                                          .addinfoitemgroup[
                                              widget.shotlistindex]
                                              [widget.projectindex]
                                          .removeAt(index);

                                      widget
                                          .shotListState
                                          .addinfoitemgroupoption[
                                              widget.shotlistindex]
                                              [widget.projectindex]
                                          .removeAt(index);

                                      if (widget
                                              .shotListState
                                              .addinfoitemgroup[
                                                  widget.shotlistindex]
                                                  [widget.projectindex]
                                              .length <
                                          4) {
                                        //globals.slidingpanelmaxheight -= 65;
                                      }

                                      widget.shotListState.inputlistenable
                                          .value += 1;

                                      int x = widget
                                          .shotListState
                                          .finalinputcustomize[
                                              widget.shotlistindex]
                                              [widget.projectindex]
                                          .length;

                                      int y = widget
                                          .shotListState
                                          .addinfolistname[widget.shotlistindex]
                                              [widget.projectindex]
                                          .length;

                                      if (widget.shotListState.scenepageedit[
                                              widget.shotlistindex]
                                          [widget.projectindex]) {
                                        for (int i = 0;
                                            i <
                                                widget
                                                    .shotListState
                                                    .finalinputcustomize[
                                                        widget.shotlistindex]
                                                        [widget.projectindex]
                                                    .length;
                                            i++) {
                                          widget.shotListState
                                                      .finalinputcustomize[
                                                  widget.shotlistindex]
                                              [widget.projectindex][i] = false;
                                        }

                                        widget.shotListState.inputtype =
                                            y - 1 + 6;

                                        widget.shotListState.getprojectindex[
                                                widget.shotlistindex] =
                                            widget.projectindex;

                                        widget.shotListState.gettitle =
                                            widget.shotListState
                                                        .addinfolistname[
                                                    widget.shotlistindex]
                                                [widget.projectindex][y - 1];

                                        if (widget.shotListState.addinfolistname[widget.shotlistindex][widget.projectindex][y - 1] == 'Subject' ||
                                            widget.shotListState.addinfolistname[widget.shotlistindex][widget.projectindex][y - 1] ==
                                                'Sound' ||
                                            widget.shotListState.addinfolistname[widget.shotlistindex][widget.projectindex][y - 1] ==
                                                'Lighting' ||
                                            widget.shotListState.addinfolistname[widget.shotlistindex]
                                                        [widget.projectindex]
                                                    [y - 1] ==
                                                'Location') {
                                          widget.onTextDetailsChosen
                                              ?.call(true);

                                          Navigator.pop(context);

                                          widget.shotListState
                                                          .finalinputcustomize[
                                                      widget.shotlistindex]
                                                  [widget.projectindex][x - 1] =
                                              true;

                                          // scenepageimagecamera.value +=1;

                                          Future.delayed(
                                              const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                                              () {
                                            double
                                                boxesAboveEditingBoxTotalHeigh =
                                                0;

                                            double
                                                editingBoxAdditionalInfoTotalHeight =
                                                0;

                                            double totalOffset = 0;

                                            // calculate total height of shot-boxes above the editing shot-box

                                            for (int shotIndex = 0;
                                                shotIndex < widget.projectindex;
                                                shotIndex++) {
                                              // if shot-container-more-detail is opened

                                              if (widget.shotListState
                                                          .shotdropdownvisibility[
                                                      widget.shotlistindex]
                                                  [shotIndex]) {
                                                // 795 = height of shot-box without any additional info

                                                boxesAboveEditingBoxTotalHeigh +=
                                                    795;

                                                for (int addInfoIndex = 0;
                                                    addInfoIndex <
                                                        widget
                                                            .shotListState
                                                            .addinfolistname[
                                                                widget
                                                                    .shotlistindex]
                                                                [shotIndex]
                                                            .length;
                                                    addInfoIndex++) {
                                                  // 58 = height of a additional info

                                                  boxesAboveEditingBoxTotalHeigh +=
                                                      58;
                                                }
                                              }

                                              // if shot-container-more-detail is closed

                                              else {
                                                // 90 = height of shot-box when it is closed

                                                boxesAboveEditingBoxTotalHeigh +=
                                                    90;
                                              }
                                            }

                                            // calculate total height of additional info boxes in the editing shot-box

                                            for (int editingAddInfoIndex = 0;
                                                editingAddInfoIndex <
                                                    widget
                                                        .shotListState
                                                        .addinfolistname[widget
                                                                .shotlistindex][
                                                            widget.projectindex]
                                                        .length;
                                                editingAddInfoIndex++) {
                                              // 58 = height of a additional info

                                              editingBoxAdditionalInfoTotalHeight +=
                                                  58;
                                            }

                                            // calculate the offset value for the scroll

                                            totalOffset =
                                                boxesAboveEditingBoxTotalHeigh +
                                                    editingBoxAdditionalInfoTotalHeight;

                                            // scroll page to the calculated offset

                                            widget.shotListState
                                                .shotitemcontroller
                                                .jumpTo(totalOffset);
                                          });
                                        } else if (widget.shotListState.addinfolistname[widget.shotlistindex]
                                                [widget.projectindex][y - 1] ==
                                            'VFX') {
                                          widget.shotListState
                                              .slidingpanelmaxheight += 151;

                                          Navigator.pop(context);

                                          BottomBar(VFXMenu(
                                            widget.shotListState.inputvisible,
                                            widget.shotlistindex,
                                            widget.shotListState
                                                    .getprojectindex[
                                                widget.shotlistindex],
                                            widget.shotListState.inputtype,
                                            widget.shotListState.gettitle,
                                            widget.addInfoFocusNodeList,
                                            widget.shotListState,
                                            onMoreDetailsChosen:
                                                (moreDetailChoice) => widget
                                                    .onMoreDetailsChosen
                                                    ?.call(moreDetailChoice),
                                          ));
                                        } else if (widget.shotListState.addinfolistname[widget.shotlistindex]
                                                [widget.projectindex][y - 1] ==
                                            'Camera') {
                                          widget.shotListState
                                              .slidingpanelmaxheight += 151;

                                          Navigator.pop(context);

                                          BottomBar(CameraMenu(
                                            widget.shotListState.inputvisible,
                                            widget.shotlistindex,
                                            widget.shotListState
                                                    .getprojectindex[
                                                widget.shotlistindex],
                                            widget.shotListState.inputtype,
                                            widget.shotListState.gettitle,
                                            widget.addInfoFocusNodeList,
                                            widget.shotListState,
                                            onMoreDetailsChosen:
                                                (moreDetailChoice) => widget
                                                    .onMoreDetailsChosen
                                                    ?.call(moreDetailChoice),
                                          ));
                                        } else if (widget.shotListState.addinfolistname[widget.shotlistindex]
                                                [widget.projectindex][y - 1] ==
                                            'Special Equipment') {
                                          widget.shotListState
                                              .slidingpanelmaxheight += 151;

                                          Navigator.pop(context);

                                          BottomBar(SpecialEquipmentMenu(
                                            widget.shotListState.inputvisible,
                                            widget.shotlistindex,
                                            widget.shotListState
                                                    .getprojectindex[
                                                widget.shotlistindex],
                                            widget.shotListState.inputtype,
                                            widget.shotListState.gettitle,
                                            widget.addInfoFocusNodeList,
                                            widget.shotListState,
                                            onMoreDetailsChosen:
                                                (moreDetailChoice) => widget
                                                    .onMoreDetailsChosen
                                                    ?.call(moreDetailChoice),
                                          ));
                                        }

                                        widget.shotListState
                                            .slidingpanelmaxheight = 1000;

                                        if (widget.shotListState.inputvisible) {
                                          //globals.slidingpanelscrollcontroller.open();
                                        } else {
                                          widget.shotListState
                                              .slidingpanelscrollcontroller
                                              .close();
                                        }

                                        /*WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(

                                          (_) => scrollToEnd(widget.projectindex));*/
                                      }

                                      if (widget.projectindex ==
                                              widget
                                                      .shotListState
                                                      .projectpagelist[
                                                          widget.shotlistindex]
                                                      .length -
                                                  1 &&
                                          widget
                                                  .shotListState
                                                  .addinfolistname[
                                                      widget.shotlistindex]
                                                      [widget.projectindex]
                                                  .length <
                                              5) {
                                        widget.shotListState
                                                .parallaxoffsetproject =
                                            1.5 + (0.21 * (y / 2.round() + 1));
                                      } else {
                                        widget.shotListState
                                                .parallaxoffsetproject =
                                            1.0 + (0.21 * (y / 2.round() + 1));
                                      }

                                      widget.shotListState.inputlistenable
                                          .value += 1;
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                              Divider(
                                  color: Colors.grey[700],
                                  thickness: 0.3,
                                  height: 0.5,
                                  indent: 16),
                            ],
                          );
                        }),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


I have tried using isScrollControlled property,
DraggableScrollableSheet,
set the constraints to full screen, wrap my content in LayoutBuilder, & wrap my content in MediaQuery but the menu has not increased to full screen. The size remains the same.
